# Apple's MVC vision code samples

Tags: swift

I know that there are a lot of patterns like MVC, MVP, MVVP etc, I don’t want to discuss which is better here (it’s prohibited by StackOverflow’s rules), I just want to find out Apple’s latest vision on that patterns, including Swift and protocols.

I want to understand what operations Apple uses itself (e.g. in their own apps) in ViewController, what in Model and how they are splitting code.

1. I have found only very old documents on Apple’s web about Cocoa MVC, is there any new documents with Swift examples?
2. Where I can to get modern Apple’s pattern vision application examples? I don’t want sample «dirty» code, I want to find out sample finished application with correct coding patterns.

Comment: I would imagine the [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html) would be along the lines of how to write an app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to take a look at the latest WWDC videos, namely [Protocol and Value Oriented Programming in UIKit Apps](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/419/)

What they show there is reminiscent of Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) approach. Their controller models are basically immutable view models.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a definitive answer without being affiliated with Apple. However, one may argue that Apple still promotes [MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html) incorporating [Protocol-Oriented Programming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/).